# how to access values from a class file in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have defined some variable with values in my settings.cs class. Is there any way to access value in javascript class.

Here is my varaibles I defined in settings.cs

```
 public static class BinaryPosition
    {
        public const string ParentIDQueryStringVariable = "test";
        public const string PlacementQueryStringVariable = "testing";
    }
```

How to access value of ParentIDQueryStringVariable and PlacementQueryStringVariable  in .js file.Thanks!!

Comment: you cannot directly access server side variables from the client side. You need to share the value with the client via the client making a request to the server and the server responding (ajax) or during the initial browser request print said variables in such a way that they are js variables.

Comment: Isn't this Java? These are keywords I've used in Java, but never in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply output the variables/values to `hidden` form fields on page load:

```
<input type="hidden" id="variable_name" runat="server" />
```

Page_Load:

```
variable_name.Value = [Your Var Value];
```